# Missing friend puzzle

Tags: wordplay

There are 9 vegetables and fruits which are good friends. They decided to meet at a grocery store one day. Everyone but one friend came. The friends who came to the meeting were:

- Jackfruit
- Kumquat
- Wax Apple
- Strawberry
- Cherry
- Avocado
- Fig
- Lemon

What's a possible name for the 9th friend who didn't come to the meeting?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain, thanks for the nice edits.

Comment: Just some random thoughts: puzzles in general should be uniquely answerable. One possible way to facilitate this is to offer a quiz-like question with suggested answers a)... b)... c)... d)... The participants' task is then to mark *the one* intended to be the answer.

Comment: @Matsmath, I agree to your suggestion. Maybe I should have given choices for the answer since there are multiple possible answers here. However, in my case puzzle, I did say "What's a possible name" to indicate that there could be multiple different answers to this question.

Comment: @VHS The problem is that questions with multiple possible answers on this site tend to be closed as "too broad".  In this case I think it's a grey area, but we're generally looking for one distinct unambiguous answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm going to go with

> **ZUCCHINI**

because

> the list given contains every letter of the alphabet except **`Z`**, so the friend must contain a **`Z`**.

Answer (score 4):

@GentlePurpleRain gave the explanation, other answers could have been:

> [Yuzu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuzu), [Arazá](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugenia_stipitata) or [Ziziphus fruit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziziphus).

Answer (score 0):

It could be:

> any vegetable, as 8 out of 9 are fruits...

Comment: Well, not all fruits contain the letter *z*. I think 8 out of 9 is a bit much.

Comment: @IAmInPLS I am afraid you misunderstood this answer. OP says "There are 9 vegetables and fruits" and lists 8 fruits (Jackfruit... Lemon). This means that it is likely that a vegetable was missing. This answerer claims, that in fact *any* vegetable could serve as an answer (irrespectively of whether they contain a letter z or not).

Comment: Oh, you're right, I thought he ahd read the answer of GPR. Nevermind then!